# How to display international characters in HTML email viewed in Windows 10 Mail?

Tags: html, character-encoding, windows-10, html-email

I am coding an email newsletter and have straightened out nearly every issue across various email services except this one stupid thing: consistently displaying an A with an acute accent on top of it (not optional, it's in the company name) in Windows 10 Mail.

Instead of getting an accented A, I get an A with a tilde on top of it followed by a narrow square.  I have tried to fix it (see below), but to no avail.

I know this issue must be down to a setting on the individual computer one happens to be using because I can open it up in Windows 10 Mail on multiple computers and see the issue only half of the time, so perhaps I am SOL. But, I'm not going to know if there's a way to make it work if I don't ask.

I started with &AAcute when I noticed it.  Then I went with UTF-8 (&#193), also not working, with or without UTF-8 specified in the head tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

No dice.  Using "A&#769" doesn't work consistently, either.   So, I started looking for answers, but everything I've waded through is only tangentially related (like displaying special characters after running them through a script for some other thing the asker is working on).  Maybe the fact that I am trying to use google's fonts has something to do with it, but the fonts I'm using do contain these characters.

Here is the relevant code as of now:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Playfair+Display|Playfair+Display+SC" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>    
    <style type="text/css">
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display);
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display+SC);
    <!-- override default font sizing -->
    div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <style type="text/css">
    .dropcaps {
    font-family: "Playfair Display SC", Georgia, serif;

    }
    .serif {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, serif;
    }
    .sansserif{
    font-family: "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <p class="dropcaps" style="Some inline styling"> A&#769; Company Name</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the first time I've ever had to do an HTML email newsletter so a main struggle here is not knowing what the heck to look up in the first place.

Comment: You should include the HTML contents (at least a minimal example) in your question.

Comment: Alright, thanks, edited.

Comment: why can't you use single `&Aacute;` instead of `A&#769;`?

Comment: Because when I use &Aacute, it shows up with a tilde, followed by a box.  So, I tried 769.  And that shows up as an I with a grave, followed by a box.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't fully support Web fonts. I'm not sure if it's fonts with a space in the name like `"Playfair Display SC"` or if it's the `""`, but it's hit and miss. Sometimes it defaults to Times New Roman, which is infuriating because it's a font with spaces in the name! Your typeface, Playfair might work just fine for you, except the extended characters.

In my case, the official font face for our company is a web font that works well with everything except Gmail (does not support Google Fonts) and Outlook. So we have a web-safe backup font we use as a fallback for other email clients.

Add this just below your regular style sheet to see if you still have problems:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
  body, table, td, a, h1, p {font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

[Ted Goas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734487/ted-goas) previously posted this even simpler code:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<style>
  * {font-family: sans-serif !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

If either of these work with `&Aacute;` then you might need to set Georgia and Arial as your specific Outlook fonts to get around the issue.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a site called [amp-what](http://www.amp-what.com/) to find substitutes for each HTML entity characters when the need arises.

The site had almost every HTML entity you can think off. Using your example from above I have added two from the site to show you how it renders.

```
<p class="dropcaps" style="Some inline styling"> A&#769; &#193; &Aacute; Company Name</p>
```

and the above renders as

> Á Á
>   Á Company Name

These came in handy when I was building emails on StrongView using XSL (escaping is a pain in XSL).

Hope this answers your question.